# Java - jframe move

Tags: java, casting, screen

I have an undecorated JFrame which I would like to move on my 2nd screen.

But when I try to move it, and reach the end of my 1st screen, it won't go farther, when it should go automaticly to the 2nd screen.

Here is a screenshot of my problem : http://www.noelshack.com/2015-33-1439202438-screenop.jpg

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Like the comment in your first question did say **At least provide some code** and a screenshot to clarify the problem.

Comment: Don't just repost same question. If you have additional informations edit the old one. Reposting same question will lead to its closing and that may lead you to question-ban.

Comment: There actually IS a screenshot and the code won't help.

Comment: @Pshemo nobody is answering to my old question so..

Comment: ...so it can mean that there wasn't enough informations, and/or that you didn't tag that question properly, so experts observing that tag didn't see your question. In both cases you should focus on improving original question first.

Comment: Anyway to increase chances of getting solution to your problem you could post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to let others actually reproduce this problem on their machines and check if their ideas are correct (we avoid posting guesses as answers).

Comment: @Pshemo I added the source code, can you see if you can help please ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't since (1) I am not Swing expert (2) I don't work on two monitors. If you will not get any answer in two days I can add bounty to your question (remind me about it then).

Comment: Alright np thank you !

Comment: Don't forget to add in your comment `@Pshemo` so I would get notified about it. Otherwise you can wait very long to my response :)